# "operates similar to" vs. "operates similarly to"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- It operates **similar** to the above-mentioned mechanism.
- It operates **similarly** to the above-mentioned mechanism.

Looking at Google, "operates similar to" and  "operates similarly to" have a similar number of results:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It+operates+similar+to%22
- https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It+operates+similarly+to%22

Comment: An actual [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+operates+similar%2C+it+operates+similarly&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20operates%20similarly%3B%2Cc0) query shows that *it operates* ***similarly*** is the only version common enough to appear on the graph at all. I don't find this surprising. Everything being equal, and exceptions aside, *-ly* adverbs will always be more common than their flat counterparts.

Comment: The actual adjectival form of the sentence (or adverbial phrase that uses the adjectival form) would be *it operates **in a similar fashion** to …*

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks very much, sounds like a great answer :-) could you please convert your comment into an answer? This way I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the second example is the correct one:

> It operates **similarly** to the above-mentioned mechanism.

The first example should probably be:

> It operates **in a similar way/manner/fashion** as the above-mentioned mechanism.

That said, you could probably get away with the first example in a conversation in spoken English. I doubt anyone would think twice about it.